# Отличия операторов от выражений

Tags: python

Читаю книгу Марка Лутца "Изучаем Python. Том 1". И там отдельное внимание отводится отличию выражений от операторов, которое я так и не понял. Можете объяснить в чем заключается отличие и дать несколько примеров?

Comment: *Expressions perform specific actions, based on an operator*. `+` - оператор, `3 + 3` - выражение

Comment: А в книге нет примеров?

Comment: Примеров в книге нет